# accessing 2d array, allocated using malloc.

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

G'day!

So if I declared the array like this:

```
int *A[5];
```

and did this:

```
A[0]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

Can I access/populate via A[0][5] with the square bracket notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most parts, arrays and pointers are interchangeable (as arrays decays to pointers), and that includes the syntax to access them. So yes, you can use the array-indexing syntax to access a pointer.

In fact, doing `a[x]` is equivalent to doing `*(a + x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access `A[0][n]` as long as that [`n`] does not run past the allocated memory region.

Maybe it's helpful to remember that in c, the index will be 1 less than the *number* of memory locations allocated.